# Prometheus.yml Environment Variables

Tags: yaml, environment-variables, prometheus

I have a current issue with Prometheus and would appreciate any input. I am spinning up a Prometheus Container as well as a Jenkins Container together as a group, and creating multiple groups based on the service I am trying to provide. Because of this, I need to be able to pass in the unique URL being generated by AWS for each Jenkins Container. I am trying to do this by passing in environment variable into the Prometheus.yml file. Has anyone done this before? Or know of how to address this problem?
[image]

I tried multiple renditions of passing in a environment variable into the yml file, however, it does not take the environment variable. Thank you for any and all advice.